# Understanding how gpt-2 tokenizes the strings

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, gpt-2

Using tutorials [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/gpt2.html) , I wrote the following codes:

```
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2Model
import torch

tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model = GPT2Model.from_pretrained('gpt2')

inputs = tokenizer("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors="pt")
outputs = model(**inputs)

last_hidden_states = outputs.last_hidden_state
```

So I realize that "inputs", consists of tokenized items of my sentence.
But how can I get the values of tokenized items? (see for example ["hello", ",", "my", "dog", "is", "cute"])

I am asking this because sometimes I think it separetes a word if that word is not in its dictionary (i.e., a word from another language). So I want to check that in my codes.

Comment: What do you mean with values? Are you looking for a mapping from `last_hidden_state` to each (untokenized) word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `tokenizer.decode` on the output of the tokenizer to get the words from its vocabulary under given indices:

```
>>> inputs = tokenizer("Hello, my dog is cute", return_tensors="pt")
>>> list(map(tokenizer.decode, inputs.input_ids[0]))
['Hello', ',', ' my', ' dog', ' is', ' cute']
```